# All products page

Tags: product, category

I am confounded by a task that I thought was very simple.

How do I make a page that will list all the products in my store. it should look like a category page (toolbar) but listing all my products sorted by the date they were created.

Comment: Please try googling next time before asking a question. Searching for "magento all products page" gives plenty of promising results.

Comment: thanks for your help i tried http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination/ and many simaler pieces of advice they don't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension is doing what you need https://github.com/ho-nl/CustomListing